How to install vinyl roll flooring over bare concrete stairs and tack strips (which are left after removing carpet from the stairs)?
This is not an important or very visible part of the house -- just the stairs from my shop-garage basement to the 1st floor of the house.
I just want to install a vinyl roll, after having pulled a toxically old and dirty carpet from the stairs, and also install any necessary trim properly and functionally. Aesthetics took a back seat on this one.
Tack strips were left on the concrete stairs (inner corners). First, I wonder if I need them at all for any underlayment?
Second, quite unwisely, I also wonder if I should skip any underlayment completely?
Third, more sensibly, I wonder which underlayment I should choose to warrant bare minimum functionality and long term reliability.
The concrete looks pretty clean for a 30 year old house, no cracks or major unevenness that I could measure.
Thanks!

Vinyl flooring does not seem the best for going over stairs.  If the same as I am thinking, it wants a smooth flat surface.  Going over the edges of stairs should crack it in very short time, since it should be tight to the stairs for safety/no gentle bends.  Using plywood/1x planks of wood glue down should last, and can be stained/painted.

I was assuming stair tread protectors would take care of cracking issues? I already have some aluminum and hardwood edge profiles for that purpose. As for smoothness, the concrete is surprisingly well top-coated, feels quite smooth compared to the concrete garage floor, so I was also thinking adhesion would not be a problem. What do you think?

The cracking would happen when it went over the edges.  If you prevent(use small pieces) or hide it, then it will be good on the flat sections.

You want a stair covering to be securely fastened—would this vinyl roll meet that requirement?

That's partly what I'm inquiring here as well, although (1) proper use of adhesives that the vinyl product requires as flooring, (2) over the vinyl fastened edge protectors, and (3) installing trim by the sides seem to be abundantly sturdier than the carpet I pulled from the stairs. I'm just getting perspectives here to avoid any mistakes that I might not foresee - especially for underlayment and whether to keep tack strips.
